# Embed HTML file in C# visual studio project and later open it using internet explorer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to embed HTML file as a help file in my C#.Net project in Visual Studio.

Later I want to open it by clicking on a LinkLabel.

Not quite sure, first how to add this file to my project resources, set the path and then open it.

It should be embedded along with the published installation file so that once user will install the application, they will be able to open this embedded file.

Answer (score 0):

Loading your embedded page could be achieved with something along these lines [from msdn](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292?wa=wsignin1.0):

```
try
{
   _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MYHTMLFile.html"));
}
catch
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error accessing resources!");
}
```

That page also details the steps for embedding.

In your case (I think) you would have to save down the stream to disk before loading with IE.